# Column value is not replacing using lookup in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace no2 values in df with the help of lookup dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
    
df=pd.DataFrame({'no1':[20,20,40,10,50],
                 'no2':[123,20,123,40,50],
                 'no3':[30,10,50,40,50]})
lookup=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C','D','E'],
                     'id':[123,20,30,40,50]})
df['no2'].replace(dict(zip(lookup.id, lookup.Name)))
```

but the output I get here is (not replaced):

```
    no1 no2 no3
0   20  123 30
1   20  20  10
2   40  123 50
3   10  40  40
4   50  50  50
```

How do I replace no2 columns and at the same time retrieving other column values in df?

Comment: Add 'inplace=True' for replace function.

Comment: what's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['no2'].replace(dict(zip(lookup.id, lookup.Name)), inplace=True)
```

or this:

```
df['no2'] = df['no2'].replace(dict(zip(lookup.id, lookup.Name)))
```